# Create tree of parts of strings out of list of systematical strings (filenames)

Tags: string, matlab, struct, tree, filenames

So I have a folder with thousands of files, all files have systematical names. I want a user to be able to select a folder, after which all the filenames are converted from a list (cell array) to some kind of tree structure. However implementing how to store this in Matlab is where I get stuck. This is what I have done so far:

```
folder = uigetdir;
files = dir([folder '\*.nii']);
nfiles = length(files);

filez = cell(nfiles, 1);
for file = 1:nfiles
    filez(file,:) = cellstr(files(file).name);
end
files = filez;

chars = zeros(nfiles, 1);
for file = 1:nfiles
    chars(file) = length(files{file});
end

filez = files;
names = struct;
for file = 1:nfiles
    curfil = filez{file};
    depth = 0;
    for curchar = 1:chars(file)
        if curchar == 1
            curmatch = strmatch(curfil(1:curchar), filez);
            prevmatch = curmatch;
        else
            prevmatch = curmatch;
            curmatch = strmatch(curfil(1:curchar), filez);
        end
        if length(curmatch) ~= length(prevmatch)
            newnamepart = curfil(1:curchar-1);
            newstructnamepart = ['X' newnamepart]; %This I did because fieldnames must start with characters
            %This is where I dont know how to go on...
        end
    end
end
```

So for every filename I check for every partial string from the start of the name which other filenames begin with the same string. If that changes I go one character back and that should be my first node in the tree. However I dont know how to create such a tree. Struct seems most like this to me, but Im not sure how to create this struct, but maybe there is another way?

Comment: Could you draw a graph, even on a piece of paper and post a scan? 
Also, can you please provide a simple example of how the tree branches out on specific filenames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea:

- Sort the names once
- Group the names in a cell array by their first character.
- Group each group by their second character.
- And so on.

You could also use containers.Map.
You cannot use struct because field names must be regular MATLAB identifieres.

```
function c = group(b, j)
    c = {};
    ch = '';
    for i=1:size(b,1)
        if ~strcmp(b(i,j), ch)
            ch = b(i,j);
            c{end+1} = [];
        end
        c{end}(end+1,:) = b(i,:);
    end

    if j<size(b,2)
        for k=1:length(c)
            c{k} = group(c{k}, j+1);
        end
    end
end

filenames = ['aba'; 'dab'; 'aaa';'abb'];
b=sortrows(filenames);
group(b,1)

ans =
{
  [1,1] =
  {
    [1,1] =
    {
      [1,1] = aaa
    }
    [1,2] =
    {
      [1,1] = aba
      [1,2] = abb
    }
  }
  [1,2] =
  {
    [1,1] =
    {
      [1,1] = dab
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, nice comprehensive answer.